# Put doubleclick event to multiple pushpins from a text file in bing maps wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, bing-maps

I have no idea how to put doubleclick events to multiple pushpins that are initialized in the program itself(not in the xaml). The program will get lat and long data from a text file. 
here's my current code:

```
public partial class BingMaps : Window
{
    string role;
    string nick;
    int countLines=0;

    public BingMaps(string value,string role2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nick = value;
        role = role2;
        setCount();
        int cLines = 0;
        Pushpin[] pushpins = new Pushpin [countLines];

        StreamReader z = new StreamReader("dorms.txt");

        while (z.Peek() > 0)
        {
            var pushpinLayer = new MapLayer();
            pushpinLayer.Name = "PushPinLayer";
            intraMap.Children.Add(pushpinLayer);
            string line = z.ReadLine();
                    string[] temp = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            var location = new Location(double.Parse(temp[3]), double.Parse(temp[4]));
            var pushpin = new Pushpin();

            pushpin.Name = "MyNewPushpin";
            pushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            pushpin.Location = location;
            pushpin.ToolTip = "" + temp[0];
            pushpins[cLines] = pushpin;
            pushpinLayer.Children.Add(pushpins[cLines]);

            cLines = cLines + 1;
        }

        z.Close();
    }

    public void setCount()
    {
        using (StreamReader cRead = new StreamReader("dorms.txt"))
        {
            while (cRead.Peek() > 0) { 
                cRead.ReadLine();
                countLines = countLines + 1;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

i'm quite new to c# so please bear with me. I need to display different data for each pushpin.

Answer (score 1):

you can register to [MouseDoubleClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.pushpin_events.aspx)

```
var pushpin = new Pushpin();
pushpin.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, ea) => {
  // do something
};
```

Comment: thank you. thank you. It worked. i had no idea it was that simple.